# Replace part of Django model structure with proxy objects

Tags: django

I've prototyped a web application with Django. Some parts of the model structure are currently  simple Django models which currently simulate the data structure of an legacy data store that I need to integrate. These so called master data will be read only for the app. The master data is (I think) exposed via a webservice to me, but I guess this is somewhat irrelevant.

Essentially I need to create some kind of proxy object, that I swap in for the current model. I would like to leave as much as possible of the remaining application code untouched. I'm aware that this will probably limit the amount of Django magic I can use for these "faked" models (no auto generated forms, no admin interface) but I'm okay with that.

Is there anything that I could use?

Comment: If you hope to make any use of the ORM for these models (queries, relationships etc), your safest bet is to use the webservice to inject the data in your database and just use your existing models.

Comment: The alternatives are either to subclass `django.db.models.Model` or to create a new database engine. bruno's suggestion would probably be a lot easier than either of those.